# Drop all the columns containing some string but excepting some with the same string

Tags: python, pandas

I have several columns containing a string "luds" I want to drop all these columns except exactly 2 columns containing the same string

For example if I have the following columns in my DataFrame:

```
    luds_mean  
    luds_std  
    luds_var  
    luds_corr  
    luds_out  
    made_mean 
    made_std 
    made_var
```

I want to retain luds_mean and luds_std columns and drop all the columns containing the string luds and left with following columns:

```
    luds_mean
    luds_std
    made_mean
    made_std
    made_var
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isin()`+`loc` accessor:

```
df=df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(['luds_var','luds_corr','luds_out'])]
```

OR

If there are more columns named luds_... then use:

```
s=df.columns.isin(['luds_mean','luds_std']) | ~df.columns.str.contains('luds_')
df=df.loc[:,s]
```